# Does the Spring Batch team offer a built-in way to read Excel files?

Tags: spring-batch

I need to pass around Excel files in a Spring batch job. The only examples I've seen use a repository that my build server does not have access to - I need something from the Spring Project itself. Is there anything like that? Or is my best course of action a home-grown solution?

Comment: How about this? https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch-extensions/tree/master/spring-batch-excel

Comment: I need the library to be in maven central, unfortunately.

Comment: See https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/kumarpankaj18/spring-batch-excel/1.0.6/

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine That's what I needed! Thanks!